# Coded Values/ Domain like with GeoServer and PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geoserver, enterprise-geodatabase, forms

Coded Values in oralce SDE are exposed trough ArcGIS Server as Coded Values in the REST API.
This ArcGIS Server REST API can provide the coded values to a webmap client to create a form with a drop list (portal/fieldmaps by exmeple) fed with these coded values.

I want to create the same flow based on ENUM type or Domain in PostGreSQL trough the GeoServer.

I check the describeFeatureType in WFS, but no useful constraints.

How a webmap OpenLyer (JS/TS) could get this list of values from PostgreSQL/PostGIS?

Comment: You could use an sql view instead, and join the code descriptions to the layer.  You could also possibly use WFS schema mapping in geoserver https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/schemamapping.html?highlight=domain

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_list.asp with this approach? @jbalk